# What would be the parameter value for embedding a SSRS report in SharePoint Site page using iFrame tag?

Tags: iframe, reporting-services, parameter-passing

I'm trying to embed a SSRS report in SharePoint Site page using iFrame tag. The report conatins parameter and I would like to pass it in the URL. However, I'm struggling with what value I should pass for the below situation. The report is connected to a Tabular model and the parameter value is shown as per the screen shot. See it has an All level and then member level. below is the iframe tag

```
<iframe width="1100" height="300" src=https:ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?report name&amp;rs:Command=Render&amp;parameterName=Casting%20Line%202&amp;rc:Parameters=false frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

embed a SSRS report in SharePoint Site page using iFrame tag. The report contains parameter and I would like to pass it in the URL. However, I'm struggling with what value I should pass for the below situation. The report is connected to a Tabular model and the parameter value is shown as per the screen shot. See it has an All level and then member level. below is the iframe tag